# Assigning unique names to objects created in for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, assign, rda

I am writing a loop where the output of each iteration has to be saved as .rda file

Suppose I have a vector of 10 locations called 'location.id'

```
dat <- data.frame(location.id = rep(c(00,11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99), each = 10), x = runif(10*10))

location.id <- c(00,11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99)
```

My loop is:

```
for(m in unique(location.id)){

   DT.grid <- dat[dat$location.id == m,]
   save(DT.grid, file = paste0("temp_",m,".rda"))
}
```

However when I load the .rda files

```
 load(file = "temp_00.rda")
 load(file = "temp_11.rda")
 load(file = "temp_22.rda")
 load(file = "temp_33.rda")
```

all the files are loaded as `DT.grid`. I understand why this is happening but I do not know how to assign different names to each .rda files in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The `rda` format locks in the variable names, so you need to set these to something different before you save, as you are saving them all as `DT.grid`. Something like...

```
for(m in unique(location.id)){
   varname <- paste0("DT.grid_", m)
   assign(varname, dat[dat$location.id == m,])
   save(varname, file = paste0("temp_",m,".rda"))
}
```

An alternative might be to use `saveRDS`, which allows you to restore to a different variable name.

Comment: `saveRDS` would bemuch cleaner in my opinion, and you just need to change `save` into `saveRDS` in the question